# Best approach to Logging in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want to console.log but then turn it off in production without deleting the logs statements.

What are other logging levels and how can i utilise them?

What benefits do logging libraries such as log4js offer?

Comment: console.log logs to the console, I've never seen a client, who browsed the net whith the console opened.

Comment: Do you have any form of build process that your scripts go through whereby you can produce a "production" build?

Comment: sometimes i use grunt or gulp for build - not always tho - so an approach with and without would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in your webpage

```
if(window.location.hostname=="example.com"){
   console.log = function(){
      return;
   }
}
```

What it will do is, if the domain name is `example.com` it will override the `console.log` functionality and it will print nothing in console.

This way it will also work in your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myAPI={isLogged:false}; 
(function(api){
    if(window.location.hostname=="dev.example.com"){
       myAPI.isLogged=true;
     }
    api.log=function(msg,level){
         if(!level){level='log'} //can be : warn, info, error, debug or log
         if( myAPI.isLogged){
              console[level](msg);
          }

    };
})(myAPI) ;
```

Then , use :

```
myAPI.log(new Date()+'    This is security check ');
```

or

```
myAPI.log(new Date()+'   Wrong password ','error');
```

---

[image: Browser console]